# How would Evil act exist in heaven?

Tags: quran, tafseer, jannah

In Quran , Surat Al-Mā'idah verse 90 ,we read:

> "ا أَيُّهَا الَّذينَ آمَنُوا إِنَّمَا الْخَمْرُ وَ الْمَيْسِرُ وَ
>   الْأَنْصابُ وَ الْأَزْلامُ رِجْسٌ مِنْ عَمَلِ الشَّيْطانِ
>   فَاجْتَنِبُوهُ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُون"
>
> "O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing
>   on] stone alters [to other than Allah ], and divining arrows are but
>   defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be
>   successful."

And ,In Surat Muĥammad verse 15,we read:

> "...مَثَلُ الْجَنَّةِ الَّتي‏ وُعِدَ الْمُتَّقُونَ فيها أَنْهارٌ مِنْ
>   ماءٍ غَيْرِ آسِنٍ وَ أَنْهارٌ مِنْ لَبَنٍ لَمْ يَتَغَيَّرْ طَعْمُهُ وَ
>   أَنْهارٌ مِنْ خَمْرٍ لَذَّةٍ لِلشَّارِبين"
>
> "Is the description of Paradise, which the righteous are promised,
>   wherein are rivers of water unaltered, rivers of milk the taste of
>   which never changes, rivers of wine delicious to those who drink..."

Now my question is , while in the Quran intoxicants are defilement from the work of satan , how would rivers of wine exist in heaven?

How would Evil act exist in heaven?

Comment: The wine in the Heaven is (will?) not intoxicant and does not make the consumer drunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we know about wine in this world it is known as intoxicant but even in this world there are some benefits but harm out weights the benefit. A side note previous nations or people who received revelations from Allah (swt) did not necessarily include the prohibition of Wine (Allah knows best) but thats what we know from this worldly life.

There is a tasfir of ibn Kathir which goes into explaining the verses concerning the characteristics of wine in paradise.

> (rivers of wine delightful to those who drink it, ) hich means that
>   the wine does not have a bad taste or foul smell like that of the
>   worldly life. Rather, it is good in its appearance, taste, smell, and
>   effect, as Allah says,
>
> (it (the wine) has no bad effects, nor does it cause intoxication.)
>   (37:47) and,
>
> (From which (the wine) they will have no headache, nor will they be
>   intoxicated.) (56:19)
>
> (white, delicious to the drinkers.)(37:46) It has been mentioned in a
>   Hadith attributed to the Prophet , "Their wine was not pressed under
>   men's feet.''
>
> http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2030&Itemid=103

Answer (score 1):

The wine in the Qur'an is not the same thing with wine in the world. It's a word in arabic شراب (sharab) means "thing to drink" in english like water. So the river means "the river you can drink from". Not an alcoholic thing.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question; the crux of the question seems to be that the first ayah condemns الخمر while the second ayah *promises* أنهار من خمر, both using (apparently) the same term to refer to "wine".