# Will we still be under the threat of punishment in Jannah?

Tags: jannah, punishment

Adam was warned when he was in Jannah. Will we be free in Jannah or will we still be under the threat of punishment?

When someone is in jannah is it still possible for him/her to be judged? If a person does a bad thing or a sin won't he/she be judged for it?

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-would-evil-act-exist-in-heaven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of you:

> Adam was warned when he was in Jannah.

Adam was warned in Jannat because he was a mortal being then. At that time, He was awaiting the Day of Judgement so He had to do good deeds and about bad deeds He was to be warned. The deeds of this world will be rewarded there and then there will be no warnings because that Jannat will be of the hereafter life. It is a common misconception that Adam was in jannah. Yes, He was but not in jannat of His deeds rather it was a temporary location for him and He must had to follow the rules there.

And as of you:

> Will we be free in Jannah or will we still be under the threat of punishment?

You have got Jannat already by your deeds and due to earthly warnings so there are no more warnings over there. You will never be under the threat of Punishment.

Allah states in Quran. Surah Az-Zukhruf Ayah no. 68:

> [image: Blockquote]
>   Translation:
>
> [To whom Allah will say], "O My servants, no fear will there be concerning you this Day, nor will you grieve,

So, there will be no fear, tear etc.. then my brother!!!

Answer (score 0):

When someone will enter Jannah he/she would be pure and sin free, as we all Do sins due to influence of Sheetan (bad-angle) and weak faith. therefore anyone who will be entering jannah would be having a strong and high level of faith and there would be no Sheetan that time.

Comment: I would like to add that there's a statement of Ali ibn Abi Talib (may Allah be pleased with him) saying "اليوم عمل بلا حساب وغداً حساب بلا عمل" (hard translaion: today is labor without judgment and tommorrow is judgment wihtout labor): This means once we are either in Janah or Jahanam there won't be any judgement

Comment: very nice addition

Comment: Shaitan is not an angel.Angels are free from sins because they do not have their own free will while jinn and humans have that free will.